# Window function for unique rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, analytics, data-analysis

I have a table like below

[image]

The main idea is to get the amount of each channel for each `orderID`.

If the channel is repeating for Id, it should take the amount only once and rest would be null.

The result should look like below

[image]

I want to do the same logic for country and source as well. If I do the pivot it should only give unique amount value for each ID on Channel, Source and Country basis and repeated value should be NULL.I have a very big data set and tough to do it in Excel

How can I do this in SQL Server? Is there any window function? Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is your data sorted? Try `case when row_number() over (partition by orderID order by whatever) = 1 then Amount end`

Comment: it is not working, it ignore other value for  same id.

Comment: Ups, of course, you must add the channel to the partitioning: `case when row_number() over (partition by orderID, Channel order by Channel) = 1 then Amount end`